# why doesn't this return an l-value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Maybe ReSharper or visual studio is wrong, but I don't think that this returns an r-value. I also don't think it actually sets the property in the $parent controller:

```
function getParentItem(path) {
    var obj = $scope.$parent;
    var param = null;
    var items = path.split(".");
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var item = items[i];
        var split = item.split("(");
        if (split.length === 2) {
             param = split[1].replace(/[\)\']/g, "");
        }
        obj = obj[split[0]];
    }
    if (param == null) {
        var thisObj = obj;
        return thisObj;
   } else {
      return { obj: obj, param: param };
   }
}
```

If I do this:

```
getParentItem($scope.someProperty) = "yadda"
```

I get error marked by probably ReSharper and I think it doesn't actually set the new value

Comment: That code isn't valid.  You can't assign to the result of a function call.

Comment: This is not about Resharper, You can't set a string value to a function.

Comment: Your function doesn't even appear to `return` anything that might resemble an l-value (apart from the fact that this is impossible in JS)? What do you expect it to assign to?

Answer (score 0):

As Amy/Volkan said your code is not valid but I think I get what you want to do. There are lots of ifs but here it goes:

if your `$scope.someProperty` is string property that you want to reassign on result of the `function getParentItem`, and your function returns object that can have that param ($scope.someProperty), first you need to figure out which path you pass in but it looks like it's some string separated by dots.

```
// so then assign result of the function to some variable
// you need to pass somePath to function
let parentItem = getParentItem(somePath);
// then change that property
parentItem[$scope.someProperty] = "yadda";
```

or another possibility what you might need would be:

```
parentItem.param[$scope.someProperty] = "yadda";
```

then do whatever you want with parentItem like put it on $scope or whatever.

If you want better help please do some jsfiddle or something.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is (and I slap my head on how stupid I was) that the leaf branches of this $scope object aren't objects themselves, and in some cases in our code they don't even exist yet. You get so used to $scope being an object you fail to realize that the final elements can't possibly be objects at least in Javascript.

So the solution was to pass the value that I wanted to set as a parameter:

```
function getParentItem(path, optionalValue)
```

On the final loop of the parent search, if optionalValue is passed, I can then set the value onto the object:

```
obj[--last parameter name--] = optionalValue;
```